# how to limite the size of WSS_Content

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, sql-server

is there a way to limite the size of the Wss_Content_dataBase, because my Wss is non stopping growing with no reason.
Is there a way with CA or I have to do it with SQL .
And is there any logical reason for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, its better to check why the Database growing unexpectedly. Couple of things to check.

- Audit logging, many time cause this issue
- Data in 2nd stage recycle bin are not count towards quota.
- Also check if there is free/unused space in your content DB

From SharePoint,

- You can limit the number of site collection in a db via Central Admin
- You can also Apply the quota to site collection, this will also restrict the Database size.
- Manage the Recycle bin

But if you want to restrict it for certain size i.e upto 100gb, then you can set that via SQL server. But keep in mind, if cap the database size then once Cap reached, your sites will become read-only. In that case you have to increase the size of DB.